# Can someone explain the do's and don'ts of .then() methods in a Reactor Mono stream?

Tags: spring, lambda, java-8, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I have two test functions below that I expect to return the same results. The first one (monoTest3) uses lambda expression in the '.then()' method. The 2nd one does not.

Why do I get the results I do?

What are some do's and don'ts when working with ReactiveX and lambda expressions?

In the code further below monoTest3 produces

```
monoVoid called
Success
----
monoVoid2 called
Success
```

and monoTest4 produces (the desired result):

```
monoVoid called
monoVoid2 called
Success
----
monoVoid2 called
monoVoid called
Success
```

And finally the code.

```
private static Mono<Void> monoVoid() {
    System.out.println("monoVoid called");
    return Mono.empty();
}

private static Mono<Void> monoVoid2() {
    System.out.println("monoVoid2 called");
    return Mono.just("Hello").then();
}

@Test
public void monoTest3() throws Exception {
    monoVoid()
            .then( v -> monoVoid2())
            .doOnSuccess(v -> System.out.println("Success"))
            .block();

    System.out.println("----");

    monoVoid2()
            .then( v -> monoVoid())
            .doOnSuccess(v -> System.out.println("Success"))
            .block();
}

@Test
public void monoTest4() throws Exception {
    monoVoid()
            .then( MonoTest::monoVoid2 )
            .doOnSuccess(v -> System.out.println("Success"))
            .block();

    System.out.println("----");

    monoVoid2()
            .then(MonoTest::monoVoid)
            .doOnSuccess(v -> System.out.println("Success"))
            .block();

}
```

Comment: I have a doubt.What does the return statement -> return Mono.just("Hello").then(); inside monoVoid2() does?How do you print that string also in the console.

Answer (score 5):

This `Mono.then(Function)` was actually deprecated in `3.0.7` and will be removed in `3.1.0` because its behavior is slightly different from all the other `then` methods in `Mono`, so we foresaw people get confused like you just did.

In 3.1.0 (currently in Milestone 2, so `3.1.0.M2`) it is now called `flatMap`, and the old flatMap that would return a `Flux` is now `flatMapMany`.

This conveys the right semantic better, and if you know a bit about `flatMap` then you can correctly infer that the "continuation Mono" can only be produced and subscribed to when the **source `Mono` is valued**.

In other words, calling `Mono.just("foo").then().then(v -> {...})` (3.0.x version) or `Mono.just("foo").then().flatMap(v -> {...})` (3.1.0 version) makes no sense, because the first `then()` has the effect that there are no values emitted. Without a value, the lambda is not invoked (its role being to *transform the value into a continuation Mono*. It makes no more sense to call `Mono.empty().then(v -> {})` for the same reason.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation.